# is it possible to configure the default user profiler location during windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10

is it possible to configure/change the default user profile location during windows 10 installation?
I tried this method before, unfortunately, I lost the link and cannot find it on google again.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The default folder is part of USERS and is used by Windows. I don’t think you can configure it beyond that. If you did change default I do not think the changes would be used anywhere.

Comment: I want to change the default user profiler from c:\user to d:\user. So that all the new user profiles are stored in D:\user

Comment: In my experience that is not a good idea. It will be better on drive C with the main USERS folder. It does not take up much space.